# How do I prepare a scanned pencil sketch for coloring in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, line-art, scanning, sketching, traditional-media

I want to color sketches in Photoshop, but when I prepared the sketch (using Levels, Hue, and other modifications) to turn it into workable line art, some details were missing. I think it depends on how you draw your sketch.

What are important steps for drawing a sketch (with pen or pencil) that is to be colored in Photoshop? A step-by-step instruction would be appreciated.

For instance, here it is the sketch  [image]

This is after my preparations in Photoshop [image]

Comment: Typically you drop the opacity of your sketch layer and draw clean lines on top of it in a new layer.  Although, if you are planning to paint it, it might be useless to draw the clean lines. Because depending on the style, you might be painting over the lines anyways.

Comment: Traditionally, you'd place a piece of vellum over the sketch and refine it with pen and ink/marker before scanning it.

Comment: actually I want clean lines , but not by drawing lines again

Comment: That will never happen. What you could do is sketch with, for example a blue pencil and ink in the clean lines. Fading out different colored lines is easy in photoshop, but you can't magically make it draw clean lines for you or remove lines that make the sketch messy.

Comment: Whether or not you should go with a line drawing depends on what you are going for. There are so many styles you could go for... Still, I felt that I should try to explain why I personally would not even bother with it. **[So here's a time-lapse video of me painting that pier looking thing](http://youtu.be/s5GKLg7AxIo)** ( That's how I saw it anyways... ). Since I paint so heavily on top of the sketch, the line drawing would just be extra  work that isn't needed. I didn't finish it cause I got a huge headache while painting that, so I figured that would be enough.

Comment: nice work ;) but I think with lines we can select evey where nd color easily

Comment: There aren't many options if you want the line art, but you don't actually want to draw it. A popular method for coloring large areas when painting with similar style to what I was using in the video, is to use `Polygonal lasso tool`. Make a selection with polygonal lasso tool, fill it with color, continue painting and refining it. In this drawing I would perhaps only use that for the background, if I were to paint the whole bg as well. The pier itself is too detailed for lasso tool in my opinion. It's faster to just brush over the lines like I'm 3 years old again.

Comment: I also like that method cause it's kinda like an extension of the sketch in the sense that it can give me new shapes and ideas to work with, which would not be the case if it was just a flat color all the way. Then again, if that is what you're going for…

Comment: yes I agree ;) thank You for that amazing video

Comment: Since I'm unable to give a proper answer, I figured I might as well share the psd file. [You can download it here if you want.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hfwxi9exuhmg6d8/Pier%20painting.psd?dl=0) I realized that it might not have been clear which brush settings I used, so: Hard round brush and in the `Windows > Brush` panel: `Shape dynamics > Size jitter control: Pen pressure` `Transfer > Opacity jitter control: Pen pressure`. Not that it matters, but I used Cintiq 12wx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you scanning your sketches? Your scanner may be able to reduce some of the extraneous noise and provide you with clean line art. Failing that, I'd recommend using a Levels adjustment layer. I was able to do this in a few minutes with levels and a quick mask with the magnetic lasso:

[image]

Comment: It is still a sketch.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking at the left side wood grains and how those disappear, your best bet is retracing those on the sketch itself. If the sketch is not available, or you just really refuse to do it, back off the contrast and zoom in and use your favorite tools to cut out or trace them by hand in-program.

Answer (score 0):

If your photo or scan of a sketch with clear lines is unevenly lighted, just applying **Levels** will never get you the desired result. It'll always be a compromise between noise, leftover shading and losing lines.

First, **pick a color channel** with the least noise. Blue usually has the lowest quality. Green is often the best. Copy the color channel into a new document.

Then follow these steps (numbers are provided for your image, adjust as needed):

1. **Duplicate layer** — "paper" layer
2. **Median** (2 pixels) — to remove small noise, depends on image resolution and noise
3. **Maximum** (10 pixels) — to remove lines, adjust until you see almost all lines disappear
4. If there're some shaded areas, use **Spot Healing Brush** to clean up
5. **Gaussian Blue** (15 pixels) — to clean up circles/squares, range bigger than used in Maximum
6. **Invert colors**, then set layer blending mode to **Liner Dodge (Add)** — to subtract the paper from the source
7. **Levels** (65 to 235) — to remove noise and increase contrast

### Result

[image]

Notice that there's no paper texture left, unlike in your result, and no lines became too light, unlike in KJP's result.